# how to pass multiple json objects in postman for a single script

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I am automating the negative scenarios for an API, using postman.

My JSON is

```
{
    "username":"cha",
     "UserID":"5665"
}
{ 
   "username":"798",
     "UserID":"UYT"
}
```

... and so on.

I want to pass *n* number of JSON objects to a single script.

```
tests["negative scenarios"]=responseCode.code===404
```

Should I use a for loop in my script?

Comment: Yes you have to use loop

Comment: It is not working if i am using the loop

Comment: can anyone help me on this please

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a csv with different data sets and pass that data to your script.

More info at:

http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/

Comment: This can be done only for a single endpoint. How can we achieve the same with multiple endpoints , when running in a collection?